# License ERROR with DB2 driver on linux

Tags: php, sql, db2, db2-luw, db2-connect

Im trying to connect to a DB2 db. ive installed driver server package from IBM 10.5.

When i try to connect to the db2 server im receiving that message:

> [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1598N An attempt to connect to the database server failed because of a licensing problem. SQLSTATE=42968 SQLCODE=-1598

How can i solve this problem? Im looking for inf on google and i cant see anything to help me.

The driver server package has been installed on debian machine to use with php/apache2 server.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to connect to a DB2 in Linux UNIX or Windows? or a DB2 for i or for z/OS?

Comment: The driver has been installed on Debian to use with php/apache server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a db2licm -l where your db2 is installed.

In your case it will tell you something like - 
Product name: "DB2 Express-C"
 Expiry date: "Expired"
 Product identifier: "db2expc"
 Version information: "9.7"
 Max number of CPUs: "2"
 Max amount of memory (GB): "2"

Notice expiry date.

Get a valid license and place it in a file *.lic

Navigate to the db2 installation folder and give db2licm -a filename. This 
command will apply the valid license.

Comment: Ummm, I dont have db2 in my laptop, does that mean I should install it or can I do a db2licm -l?

Comment: If your laptops OS is Linux then yes. That command wont work on Windows PC. You will have to go thru the Installation docs to identify how you check your license based on OS

Comment: Mine is Windows. So how do I do this?

Comment: Honestly - I am not sure about how to do it on Windows.

Comment: Damn! Another dead end. Thanks anyway

Comment: Did you find how to do it on Windows?